# Error to request exposed api rest through wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

¡Hi everybody!

I have an api developed with Springboot and swagger.This Api is configured into WSO2 Api manager.

I did new subscription for doing requests to Api througt WSO2  Api Manager but when I try do request, it's fail because the WSO2 Api Manager url generated has duplicate http protocol.I'm using his owns Api console from WSO2 Api Store to test the requests.

This is an example of the error:

[image]

¿Someone knows what is the reason why  the http protocol is duplicated?

Edit: Seems that if I try to test from internal server ip "https://<<internal_server_ip>>:9443/store/" the request url generated it's ok. But from external server ip "https://<<external_server_ip>>:9443/store/" https is duplicated as last example image.

I've updated our WSO2 Api Manager version from 2.6.0 to 3.2.0 but
I still have a similar error. Https protocol doensn't appear duplicated but now always appear localhost hostname instead of Ip adress.

[image]

¿Someone knows what is the reason why hostname is localhost and not Ip adress?

¡Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone knows what is the reason why the http protocol is duplicated?

Please check whether you have correctly assigned the gateway URL value in the **GatewayEndpoint** element that is located under the APIGateway configurations in the **api-manager.xml** file.

Also, try to re-publish the API and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you a lot Saranki for your reply. I got solve the problem. First, I was importing the Api from swagger file but you had suggested, the gateway endpoint was wrong. In addition, the new API Management version 3.2.0 use other port by default instead of 9443 so I had to open the new port on Cloud Firewall. Both of this solutions solve the problem. Thank you again! Best regards, David :)